# "sync too many contacts deletes" and "sync is currently experiencing problems. it will be back shortly"

Tags: android, gmail, contacts, android-contacts, google-contacts-api

I got the problems about:
"sync too many contact deletes"
and
"sync is currently experiencing problems. it will be back shortly"

I tried almost solutions and have googled almost sites, there is no solutions helpful for me.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found it out that we can do by:

- Export contacts to vCard.
- Import them to gmail contacts in browser.
- Try to deletes contacts and sync

if it not works, please delete all contacts in your phone and all contacts in your gmail contacts. Then use your exported vCard to import again.

Answer (score 0):

My tablet runs on Android 4.1 Jelly Bean and has no Contact application in the Apps folder so that contact data can be deleted using the methods suitable for mobile phones and often quoted in help pages. After much faffing about the only way I found to get rid of the "Too many contact deletions" message and resulting failure to sync automatically was by deleting the Google account. This assumes that your contacts and calendar data are held on Google's servers and a backup copy of the data has been taken first. Turn on airplane mode or otherwise shut off connectivity.

1. Go to `Settings > Accounts > Google` and remove the account accepting the warning message.
2. Check that your contacts and calendar are indeed empty then add the account back in.
3. You will need to sign on to your Google account so have your password ready.
4. Turn on sync and off you should go.

It worked for me.